# Access Pod By Internet From AKS Private Cluster

Tags: azure, nginx, kubernetes, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I have a fully Private AKS Cluster, I have it setup on a private VNET which I access through an Azure Bastion to run kubectl commands. I have also set up a DevOps pipeline which uses a self hosted agent to run commands on the private cluster. All my pods and ingresses seem to be running fine. However, when I try to access my ingress using a hostname (by mapping the public ip) I am getting a 404 not found. When verifying against my public cluster setup, I don't see any issues. Can someone please shed some light on why I cannot access my pod which appears to be running fine?

Also, it seems I cannot access the external IP of the ingress even on the virtual machine which is on the virtual network. But I can run the kubectl commands and access the kubernetes dashboard.

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: app-auth
  labels:
    environment: staging
  name: app-auth-staging # The name of the app
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: app-auth-staging
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-auth-staging
  namespace: app-auth
  labels:
    app: app-auth-staging
    environment: staging # The environment being used
    app-role: api # The application type
    tier: backend # The tier that this app represents
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app-auth-staging
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app-auth-staging
        environment: staging
        app-role: api
        tier: backend
      annotations:
        build: _{Tag}_
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth
          image: auth.azurecr.io/auth:_{Tag}_ # Note: Do not modify this field.
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          env:
            - name: ConnectionStrings__ZigzyAuth # Note: The appsettings value being replaced
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: connectionstrings
                  key: _{ConnectionString}_ # Note: This is an environmental variable, it is replaced accordingly in DevOps
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          readinessProbe:
            tcpSocket:
              port: 80
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 10
          livenessProbe:
            tcpSocket:
              port: 80
            initialDelaySeconds: 15
            periodSeconds: 20
          volumeMounts:
            - name: secrets-store-inline
              mountPath: "/mnt/secrets-store"
              readOnly: true
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: agentpool
                operator: In
                values:
                - general
      volumes:
        - name: secrets-store-inline
          csi:
            driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
            readOnly: true
            volumeAttributes:
              secretProviderClass: "aks-provider"
            nodePublishSecretRef:                       
              name: aks-prod-credstore
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: aks-prod-acrps
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-auth-staging-ingress-main # The name of the ingress, ex: app-auth-ingress-main
  namespace: app-auth
  labels:
    environment: staging
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "GET, POST, OPTIONS"
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "https://admin.example.com"
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-credentials: "true"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - stagingauth.app.com # Modify
      - frontend.21.72.207.63.nip.io 
      - aksstagingauth.app.com
      secretName: zigzypfxtls
  rules:
  - host: stagingauth.app.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: zigzy-auth-staging # Modify
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
  - host: frontend.21.72.207.63.nip.io 
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: app-auth-staging # Modify
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
  - host: aksstagingauth.app.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: app-auth-staging # Modify
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
```

Comment: hope you created the ingress record and ingress controller is running inside cluster. also you DNS is pointing to ingress external IP.

Comment: @HarshManvar I created the ingress inside the cluster. Can you please clarify my DNS is pointing to ingress external IP?

Comment: you created ingres but checked ingress controller external IP ? `kubectl get svc -n <ingress controller namespace>` for example if using ingress-nginx controller `kubectl get svc -n ingress-nginx`

Comment: @HarshManvar Yes I have mapped the external IP of the ingress to hostnames in the ingress file but it is still showing as 404 when I access the external IP and hostnames. Do private AKS cluster work different in this regard?

Comment: can you share the ingress file in question? also if you want to use host name like example.com you have to add ingress external  IP in DNS as A record.

Comment: @HarshManvar I have edited my main post. I believe I have it mapped correctly as a DNS record but it is somehow not working like my public cluster. Also I have edited the actual addresses in the code so as not to expose our site

Comment: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#gce-gke

Comment: @HarshManvar Can you please specify what you want me to look at in this url. Nevermind I see it let me check

Comment: thought it's might be an issue of DNS but looks like it's due to some port block or firewall concerns. as you getting 404 which mean request might be hitting to ingress. can you check logs of ingress controller ?

Comment: @HarshManvar Thanks that helped me figure it out! I forgot I changed the ingress class of my controller and I just had to point to the right one

Comment: great glad to hear that.

Comment: @James please post your solution as an answer.